# Why do you increment the value of the offset by 4 for buffer overflow?

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am working my way through basic windows buffer overflow and am having a hard time understanding why after using a tool like pattern_create.rb then patter_offset from metasploit framework to determine the EIP at the time of the crash why I need to add 4 that value?

For example, if I run a script that sends the pattern created by pattern_create.rb and I check Immunity Debugger for the value of EIP at the time of the crash (then determine the offset using pattern_offset) I apparently then need to increment that value by 4 to overwrite the value of EIP and replace the return address?

My understanding was that when return is called the value at that spot is popped into EIP to be executed next so I don't understanding why that value needs to be incremented by 4 so as to point to ESP instead? Why does the offset discovered through the above mentioned process not overwrite the return address entirely without adding 4?

How is it that the offset only points to the beginning of the return value to be overwritten and does not over-right?

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Edit: Am I just misunderstood what is meant by offset? is the metasploit tool finding the value at EIP (as requested) then providing me with it minus 4 or the value at the beginning of it? This is the only explanation I can think of.